# Annoying autocompletion in VS Code for JavaScript when working with DOM

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on JavaScript in VS Code and facing an issue with autocompletion. When I type:

```
let pool = document.querySelector('section#a')
pool.style //some suggested method appears after 'style'
```

VS Code automatically suggests `computedStyleMap`. It's annoying when I ignored it and continue typing `.`, it replaces `style` with the suggested method.

so, I have to manually type a space before the dot to prevent this, which is quite frustating. Is there a way to disable this specific autocompletion behavior or adjust settings?

Comment: You can go to settings then type `suggest` in the search bar. You will then see an option called `Text Editor:` and a sub-option inside `Suggestions`

Comment: Never thought that the solution as simple as uncheck the settings. Thank you so much